# Venetian baroque keyboard pieces

Tags: classical-music, baroque

I'm looking for keyboard pieces written in the musical baroque period by Venetian composers. With "keyboard" I mean a solo piece that could be played on harpsichord or on a piano. I'm not interested in a "true" organ music that requires the pedalboard.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of the main composers (Vivaldi, Monteverdi, Marcello, Albinoni, Caldara, etc...) lacks of this kind of pieces.

Anyway, I'm open to other composers who meet at least one of the following criteria:

- a baroque composer bound in some way to Venice (i.e. lived in the nearby, or known for a trip to Venice, etc...)
- the piece it self is bound in some way to Venice (i.e. Mendelssohn Venetian Boat songs from Lieder ohne Worte) - but with the composer died before 1900
- more widely - as last chance - a piece of a baroque/classical composer that deals with the subject of the "air" (not musical form, the air we breath)

My research is for an event in a primary school, with a themed evening about baroque, Venice and air.

Comment: Re "air": So something like Vivaldi's flute concerto *La tempesta di mare* (Concerto per flauto traverso, archi e basso continuo nº 1 in Fa maggiore, op. 10, RV 433), but for harpsichord? Because a storm at sea is fast moving air?

Comment: @njuffa something like that, yes. Or Debussy *Pour invoquer Pan, dieu du vent d'été* for example

Comment: If you just want a Venetian Baroque composer who wrote music for the harpsichord (without a reference to "air"), check whether Baldassare Galuppi's (1706-1785) harpsichord sonatas suit you.

Comment: @njuffa thanks, I didn't remember Galuppi was Venetian!

Answer (score 2):

- [Storace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernardo_Storace) might somehow match, at least his surviving sheet music is published in Venice, even if  no biographic details are known.
- Another candidate is [Benedetto Marcello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedetto_Marcello) (no idea, whther one of the suites contain an air movement).